# Django template displaying nothing

Tags: python, django, textfield

I have a TextField(text area) form on my page where users can submit comments and have them displayed.

I've left several comments and none of them is showing up. There's just a bunch of empty HTML tags for all the comments i left, cant figure what the issue is

**models.py:**

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    user_commented = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    list_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    list_author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user_commented}, {self.date_time}, {self.comment}"
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['comment']
```

**views.py**

```
commentform = CommentForm()

comment = CommentForm(request.POST)

if "comment" in request.POST:
            if comment.is_valid:
                comment_data = Comments.objects.create(list_title=title, user_commented=username, list_author=author, comment=comment)
                comment_data.save()
                comment_data = list(Comments.objects.all().filter(list_title=title))
                return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                        "form": form,
                        "listing": listing_object,
                        "checkbox": checkbox,
                        "commentform": commentform,
                        "max_bid": max_bid,
                        "comments": comment_data
                    })
```

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'listing' listing.title %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ commentform }}
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" name="comment">
    </form>

    <div class="comment">
        <h5>Comments</h5>
        {% for comment in comments %}
            <p>{{ comments.user_commented }}</p><span>{{ comments.date_time }}</span>
            <p>{{ comments.comment }}</p>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

**GET request:**
I grabbed all the comments from the database into a variable before passing it to the GET request like so

```
comment_data = list(Comments.objects.all().filter(list_title=title))


return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "form": form,
        "listing": listing_object,
        "checkbox": checkbox,
        "commentform": commentform,
        "max_bid": max_bid,
        "users": author,
        "comments": comment_data
    })
```

Comment: You don't show comments if the method is `GET`

Comment: `<form action="{% url 'listing' listing.title %}" method="POST">` its not

Comment: The HTML is irrelavent

Comment: Can you elaborate please

Comment: Please include the code that is called on a GET request

Comment: When people just view the page, before posting a comment, the request method will be GET but all your code is inside a if statement that can only happen inside POST requests

Comment: Ah, i get you now, i did pass the comments into the GET request too, i'll post it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did wrong here:

```
      {% for comment in comments %}
            <p>{{ comment.user_commented }}</p><span>{{ comment.date_time }}</span>
            <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p> #You had added comments here instead of comment
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
```

According to for loop, you had added `comments` instead of `comment`.